# Загрузка приложением CPU

Tags: android, консоль, cpu, top

Запустил в эмуляторе терминала команду top. И она вывела следующие процессы в системе (см. вложение).
Вопроса два. 800%CPU это 8 ядер по 100% как я понимаю.
А что значит на первом приложении 115%? Надо разделить на 8 и получить среднюю нагрузку на 1 ядро? Или как правильно расшифровать этот показатель?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего процесс использует несколько потоков которые в сумме нагружают несколько ядер

Comment: Не знаю, прокатит ли это в андроиде, но попробуйте запустить top с опцией `-H` — так он покажет каждый поток в отдельности, и они по идее не должны будут грузить больше 100%

Comment: То есть в сумме всех значений столбца CPU должно быть макс 800?

Comment: Сделал с ключом -H у этого приложения два потока. в каждом более 100% значения